# Possible to access gdata api when using Java App Engine?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, gdata-api

I have a dilemma where I want to create an application that manipulates google contacts information. The problem comes down to the fact that Python only supports version 1.0 of the api whilst Java supports 3.0.

I also want it to be web-based so I'm having a look at google app engine, but it seems that only the python version of app engine supports the import of gdata apis whilst java does not.

So its either web based and version 1.0 of the api or non-web based and version 3.0 of the api.

I actually need version 3.0 to get access to the extra fields provided by google contacts.

So my question is, is there a way to get access to the gdata api under Google App Engine using Java?

If not is there an ETA on when version 3.0 of the gdata api will be released for python?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a look into the google data api protocol which seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google Data API Java Client : [link1](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/)

Getting Started with the Google Data Java Client Library [link2](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/java_client_lib.html)

I guess this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use GDATA apis for my JAVA appengine webapp. So GDATA can be used with JAVA runtime.

From http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html

> Yes, the Google Data Java client library can be used in App Engine, but you need to set a configuration option to avoid a runtime permissions error.
>  Add the following to your **appengine-web.xml** file:

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="com.google.gdata.DisableCookieHandler" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

> If the following is not included, you
>   may see the following exception:
>   java.security.AccessControlException:
>   access denied (java.net.NetPermission
>   getCookieHandler)